# Shorter code inside while loop

Tags: php, variables

I am using a while loop that saves data... i want to shorten the lengthy code
i need to write for each item and use the $counter value as part of the variable.

I would have searched and tested on my own but i dont know how to define the search
so i would try to explain....

**Say i have the need to do something like this:**

```
    $xvalue_1 = $_POST['VALUE 1'];
    $xvalue_2 = $_POST['VALUE 2'];
    $xvalue_3 = $_POST['VALUE 3'];
    $xvalue_4 = $_POST['VALUE 4'];
    $xvalue_5 = $_POST['VALUE 5'];

    $yvalue_1 = $_POST['VALUE 1'];
    $yvalue_2 = $_POST['VALUE 2'];
    $yvalue_3 = $_POST['VALUE 3'];
    $yvalue_4 = $_POST['VALUE 4'];
    $yvalue_5 = $_POST['VALUE 5'];

    $zvalue_1 = $_POST['VALUE 1'];
    $zvalue_2 = $_POST['VALUE 2'];
    $zvalue_3 = $_POST['VALUE 3'];
    $zvalue_4 = $_POST['VALUE 4'];
    $zvalue_5 = $_POST['VALUE 5'];

    // SAVING HERE
    some_save_todb_func($xvalue_1);
    some_save_todb_func($xvalue_2);
    some_save_todb_func($xvalue_3);
    some_save_todb_func($xvalue_4);
    some_save_todb_func($xvalue_5);

    some_save_todb_func($yvalue_1);
    some_save_todb_func($yvalue_1);
    some_save_todb_func($yvalue_1);
    some_save_todb_func($yvalue_1);
    some_save_todb_func($yvalue_1);

    some_save_todb_func($zvalue_1);
    some_save_todb_func($zvalue_1);
    some_save_todb_func($zvalue_1);
    some_save_todb_func($zvalue_1);
    some_save_todb_func($zvalue_1);
```

.
**How can shorten it using a foreach**
This example clearly doesnt work... need to make it work
i tried doing this using "variables varible" and failed...

```
        $xvalue_1 = $_POST['VALUE 1'];
    $xvalue_2 = $_POST['VALUE 2'];
    $xvalue_3 = $_POST['VALUE 3'];
    $xvalue_4 = $_POST['VALUE 4'];
    $xvalue_5 = $_POST['VALUE 5'];

    $yvalue_1 = $_POST['VALUE 1'];
    $yvalue_2 = $_POST['VALUE 2'];
    $yvalue_3 = $_POST['VALUE 3'];
    $yvalue_4 = $_POST['VALUE 4'];
    $yvalue_5 = $_POST['VALUE 5'];

    $zvalue_1 = $_POST['VALUE 1'];
    $zvalue_2 = $_POST['VALUE 2'];
    $zvalue_3 = $_POST['VALUE 3'];
    $zvalue_4 = $_POST['VALUE 4'];
    $zvalue_5 = $_POST['VALUE 5'];

    $counter = 1;
    while($counter < 5) {

        // TRYING TO USE THE COUNTER AS VARIABLE 
        // WHICH IS PART OF THE VARIABLE...
        some_save_todb_func($xvalue_{$counter});
        some_save_todb_func($yvalue_{$counter});
        some_save_todb_func($zvalue_{$counter});

        $counter++;
    }
```

I have no official PHP training so my apologies if my question seems idiotic.
Would apreaciate your help here...

**EDIT 1 (and hopefully last edit)**

```
$xvalue_1 = 'xvalue 1 var';
$xvalue_2 = 'xvalue 2 var';
$xvalue_3 = 'xvalue 3 var';
$xvalue_4 = 'xvalue 4 var';
$xvalue_5 = 'xvalue 5 var';

$yvalue_1 = 'yvalue 1 var';
$yvalue_2 = 'yvalue 2 var';
$yvalue_3 = 'yvalue 3 var';
$yvalue_4 = 'yvalue 4 var';
$yvalue_5 = 'yvalue 5 var';

$zvalue_1 = 'zvalue 1 var';
$zvalue_2 = 'zvalue 2 var';
$zvalue_3 = 'zvalue 3 var';
$zvalue_4 = 'zvalue 4 var';
$zvalue_5 = 'zvalue 5 var';

$counter = 1;
while($counter < 6) {

    $xvalue =   'xvalue_'.$counter;
    $yvalue =   'yvalue_'.$counter;
    $zvalue =   'zvalue_'.$counter;

    echo $$xvalue."<br />";
    echo $$yvalue."<br />";
    echo $$zvalue."<br />";

    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: Though it is possible to do that with [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) (yeah, terrible name), you should use arrays.

Comment: Can you share an example..?? please remmember that i am trying to downsize the code and not Inflate it ;)

Comment: Well, with your given example I'd make it 5 lines or so of code, but it really depends on your actual use case. E.g. I assume `$_POST` names are not sequential as in your example right? And will you need those variables after saving them to the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), or create an array (and loop through that array afterwards) to do this. It seems that if you get your loop control structures right, you may as well call your database save function in the loop instead of assigning variables.

```
$letters = array('x', 'y', 'z');
$max_number 5;

$array = array();

foreach($letters as $letter) {

    for($i = i; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        // set variable variable
        $var_name = $letter . 'value_' . $i;
        $$var_name = $_POST['VALUE ' . $i];
        // you probably won't need to do that using these loops though, just call the function:
        some_save_todb_func( $_POST['VALUE ' . $i] );
        // ... or set array value
        $array[$varname] = $_POST['VALUE ' . $i];
    }

}
```

The exception to what I said up the top is if you are inserting a lot of similar data into the same table, you might want to speed up your script by using **one** insert query, in which case use the array option above, then call `$str_of_values = implode("','", $array);` to get a **string** you can insert in a MySQL query like this: `...VALUES('$str_of_values')`.

Depends what you're after, but variable variables will assign that long list you've got up the top and save you file size...

Comment: So... Sticking to my example (plz ;) i have add an edit to my answer - is this the "right" way?

Comment: Ok.. my edit works - thanks for you help understanding this ;)